# Causal relationships with a specific correlation structure

Tags: correlation, causality, dag

Can three distinct causal relationships (labeled A, B, and C) be constructed to yield a common targeted correlation matrix (e.g., $r_1=0.6,~r_2=0.5,~r_3=0.4$) as depicted in the figure below? [image: targeted correlations]
If constructing all the three causal relationships proves unfeasible, how about two cases instead?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What does it mean for 'causal relationships to be constructed'? Do scenarios A, B and C apply at the same time? Then $Z$ and $Y$ have incompatible oriented edges in B and C. Do scenarios A, B and C apply separately? Then, since independence implies uncorrelatedness and you don't have any additional variables in the DAG (assuming faithfulness), you cannot fulfill the target correlation matrix.

Comment: @Kuku The three scenarios A, B, and C are intended to be applied simultaneously. The absence of a causal relationship (e.g., between $Y$ and $Z$ in scenario A) indicates no direct causation, but it does not necessarily imply no correlation. While achieving all three cases simultaneously might be challenging, I hope achieving at least two of them would be feasible.

Comment: When $(X,U,V)$ is a standard trivariate Normal random variable, set $Y=0.6X+\sqrt{1-0.6^2}U$ and $Z=0.4X+(13/40)U+\sqrt{1-0.4^2-(13/40)^2}V.$

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the excellent solution for case A! Do you have any suggestions for the other two cases?

Comment: You can construct them in a similar fashion.